# data variable undefined when I use setInterval in vue methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

when I get a data variables from vue data data is undefined how can I get a variable for realtime exchange in vue methods

```
export default {
      name: 'Chart',
      components: {
     },
     data(){
         return {
             firstUpdateTime:0,
             price:[],
             timeLable:[],
             maxPrice: 20000,
         }
     },
     methods:{

         calculateChart : function(){
             var a = 300;
             setInterval(() => 

               this.firstUpdateTime ++;
               a--;

            );}, 30000);


         }
     },

}
```

Comment: In its present form the code in the question won't run. I assume there's supposed to be a `{` after the `=>` and the line `);}, 30000);` is probably meant to be something else. Could you update the code to match the code you're actually running? It would also be helpful if you could provide details of how you're establishing that data is `undefined`. Are you getting an error, or do you have some logging, or what?

Comment: also you should initialzie and destroy this interval method

Comment: I can't reproduce your current problem, because this code in this question seems to work just fine. You are either leaving out something, or rewrote something. Log `this` to see what you are working with, and remember that `function () { ... }` resets `this`, while `() => { ... }` does not. Could have something to do with the build process, or you could be seeing old output from old components, since you do not destroy your interval.